# design pattern: how to add optional params for methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I hava a util class:

```
public class ImageCompressionUtil {

  public static void compressor(InputStream image, OutputStream outputStream, double quality,
      String outputFormat) throws IOException {
    Thumbnails.of(image).scale(1).outputQuality(quality).outputFormat(outputFormat).
        toOutputStream(outputStream);
  }

  public static void compressor(byte[] image, OutputStream outputStream, double quality,
      String outputFormat) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
    Thumbnails.of(inputStream).scale(1).outputQuality(quality).
        outputFormat(outputFormat).toOutputStream(outputStream);
  }

  public static byte[] compressor(InputStream image, double quality, String outputFormat)
      throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Thumbnails.of(image).scale(1).outputQuality(quality).
        outputFormat(outputFormat).toOutputStream(outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }

  public static byte[] compressor(byte[] image, double quality, String outputFormat) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Thumbnails.of(inputStream).scale(1).outputQuality(quality).
        outputFormat(outputFormat).toOutputStream(outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }
}
```

Among these methods, we could see some duplicated params like `outputStream`,`quality`,`outputFormat`.
How to rewrite this class so that I can use this class like such patterns:

```
// no outputstream/quality/outputFormat specified, default values are used;
ImageCompressionUtil.compressor(image);

// specifiy outputstream or quality or outputFormat
ImageCompressionUtil.compressor(image, outputstream);
ImageCompressionUtil.compressor(image).quality(quality);
ImageCompressionUtil.compressor(image).outputFormat(outputFormat);

// both quality and outputFormat are specified
ImageCompressionUtil.compressor(image).quality(quality).outputFormat(outputFormat);

...
```

Comment: Looks like a builder to me.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a need of the Builder pattern since Java supports neither named parameters nor default arguments (I didn't pick a deep look into your methods, but in general dispatching overloads from one to another may be better than copying the same code to multiple places). Welcome to the Java world...

Comment: You can use the builder pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: it looks like the builder pattern.

You would only need two `compressor` methods that would return an instance of the `Compressor` class (the builder):

```
public class ImageCompressionUtil {
    public Compressor compressor(InputStream image) {
        return new Compressor(image);
    }

    public Compressor compressor(byte[] image) {
        return new Compressor(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
    }
}
```

The `Compressor` class would look like this:

```
public class Compressor {
    private final Thumbnail thumbnail;

    public Compressor(InputStream image) {
        this.thumbnail = Thumbnail.of(image).scale(1);
    }

    public Compressor quality(double quality) {
        thumbnail.outputQuality(quality);
        return this;
    }

    public Compressor outputFormat(String format) {
        thumbnail.outputFormat(format);
        return this;
    }

    public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) {
        thumbnail.toOutputStream(outputStream);
    }

    public byte[] toBytes() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        writeTo(out);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

So you would first create a compressor, then set the parameters, and then either write the result to an `OutputStream` or get it as an array of bytes.

One thing that is not clear is which class should close the `InputStream`.

Note that the `Compressor` class is not much different than what I have called the `Thumbnail` class (what is returned by `Thumbnails.of()`), and you could directly return the result of `Thumbnails.of(image).scale(1)` instead of creating another class.

Comment: It's builder *plus* the fluent interface pattern. Builder doesn't necessarily require fluency; it may use plain setters.

Comment: @Bohemian OK, thanks.